# Can't get MATCH AGAINST to work with wildcard

Tags: mysql

Longtime reader, first time asker here.

I'm putting together a MySQL database of books as a learning project.  I'm trying to implement full-text search with PHP and MySQL.  It's working so far, but the `*` truncation operator isn't working as expected.  I'll omit the PHP for simplicity, since the behavior is the same when I run the queries in PhpMyAdmin too.

```
    SELECT * FROM Mainbooks WHERE MATCH(Title,Author,Description) AGAINST('blaze')
```

returns one row containing the entry for "Blaze" by Richard Bachman, but

```
    SELECT * FROM Mainbooks WHERE MATCH(Title,Author,Description) AGAINST('blaz*')
```

returns no rows.  For another example,

```
    SELECT * FROM Mainbooks WHERE MATCH(Title,Author,Description) AGAINST('Sacks')
```

returns the row containing "Migraine" by Oliver Sacks, but

```
    SELECT * FROM Mainbooks WHERE MATCH(Title,Author,Description) AGAINST('Sack*')
```

returns no rows.  A slightly different case is

```
    SELECT * FROM Mainbooks WHERE MATCH(Title,Author,Description) AGAINST('blaze*')
```

or
        SELECT * FROM Mainbooks WHERE MATCH(Title,Author,Description) AGAINST('migraine*')

both of which return results, apparently ignoring the `*` character.  I'm running this in MAMP, if that makes any difference.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `BOOLEAN MODE` when using `*` operator

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

```
SELECT * FROM Mainbooks 
WHERE MATCH(Title,Author,Description) AGAINST('blaz*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: Thanks!  That was it.  I'll have to find a different way to do what I wanted to do.  I wanted to truncate plural search terms with a PHP function, but I like the idea of the natural language search's relevance-sorting feature.